# How to Register a dll in the batch file

Tags: windows-10

I have some dll's (Sample.dll) and I want to register those dll's using batch when I run my text.bat file.

But when I tried the below command:

```
Do Regsvr32 /S "%File%\RL_Advice420.dll" "%DestinationDrive%"
```

I was facing an error like there was no command for `Do`.

Comment: What should **Do** do, in your case? Have you tried without **Do**?

Comment: When i try without Do it was not prompting any message, that how i need to check whether the Dll got registered or not.

Comment: I am asking, because as far as I know, **Do** is only used to create **Loops**. I have never seen **Do** standalone (without any Loop).

Comment: Thanks for that, actually i don't know like how to register, so i tried the sample command as mentioned above, can you please let me know if any other command was there for registering Dll in the batch file.

Comment: To register a DLL, this command should be enough: `regsvr32 your_lib.dll`

Answer (score 2):

As answer:

To register a DLL on Windows, this command should be enough:

`regsvr32 your_lib.dll`

I am not sure, but I highly assume that you need **admin** privileges.

see here: https://ss64.com/nt/regsvr32.html

Answer (score 1):

#### When I tried the below command:

> ```
> Do Regsvr32 /S "%File%\RL_Advice420.dll" "%DestinationDrive%"
> ```
>
> I was facing an error like there was no command for `Do`.

`Do` is not a valid command in a batch file.

Try the following command:

```
Regsvr32 /S "%File%\RL_Advice420.dll"
```

**Syntax**

> ```
> REGSVR32 [/U] [/S] [/N] /I:[CommandLine] DLL_Name
> ```
>
> Key
>
> - `/u`          Unregister Server.
> - `/s`          Silent, do not display dialogue boxes.
> - `/i`          Call `DllInstall` to register the DLL.
>                (when used with /u, it calls dll uninstall.)
> - `/n`          Do not call DllRegisterServer, you must use this option with /i.
> - `CommandLine`  An optional command line for `DllInstall`
> - `/c`          Console output (old versions only).
>
> Source [Regsvr32 - Register a DLL - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/regsvr32.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [regsrv32](https://ss64.com/nt/regsvr32.html) - Register or unregister a DLL.Register or unregister a DLL.

Comment: +1 That's all I want to say. Also not all DLL can be registered with `regsvr32`. The DLL should have `DllRegisterServer()` export function.